# "TypeError: callback is not a function" after upgrading to stencil 1.12.0

Tags: bigcommerce

I just upgraded to the latest version of stencil-cli, and now getting an error anytime I edit, or simply just open any template file. I upgraded from version 1.8 by running:

`npm install -g @bigcommerce/stencil-cli`

After the new version installed, I ran `stencil start`, and everything seemed to be working fine.

Then, I opened a template file to edit `vi templates/components/common/header.html`. As soon as the file opens, stencil-cli outputs the following error, and shuts down:

```
/Users/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/lib/template-assembler.js:26
            return callback(err);
                   ^

TypeError: callback is not a function
    at /Users/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/lib/template-assembler.js:26:20
    at /Users/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/lib/template-assembler.js:91:20
    at /Users/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:421:16
    at iteratorCallback (/Users/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:998:13)
    at /Users/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:906:16
    at ReadFileContext.callback (/Users/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/lib/template-assembler.js:112:24)
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:303:13)
```

This occurs everytime a template file is openend or edited. It does not seem to occur when I edit a sass file. So far, I have only seen it when editing/opening/saving something in the `templates/` directory.

I am running node `v4.2.1` in case that matters.

Any idea why this is happening all of a sudden? Is there some sort of bug with the latest version?

**UPDATE**

After adding a log statement as suggested in the comments, the full output is now:

```
[Error: The following template(s) are/is missing:
function (err, v) {
            results[index] = v;
            callback(err);
        }]
/Users/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/lib/template-assembler.js:27
            return callback(err);
                   ^

TypeError: callback is not a function
    at /Users/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/lib/template-assembler.js:27:20
    at /Users/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/lib/template-assembler.js:92:20
    at /Users/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:421:16
    at iteratorCallback (/Users/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:998:13)
    at /Users/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:906:16
    at ReadFileContext.callback (/Users/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/lib/template-assembler.js:113:24)
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:303:13)
```

**UPDATE**

After adding additional debugging as per the comments, here is the new output. There is a long repetitive sequence of things like this:

```
layout/base function (err, v) {
            results[index] = v;
            callback(err);
        } undefined
layout/empty function (err, v) {
            results[index] = v;
            callback(err);
        } undefined
components/carousel function (err, v) {
            results[index] = v;
            callback(err);
        } undefined
components/account/add-wishlist function (err, v) {
            results[index] = v;
            callback(err);
        } undefined
components/account/address-list function (err, v) {
            results[index] = v;
            callback(err);
        } undefined
components/account/edit-account function (err, v) {
            results[index] = v;
            callback(err);
        } undefined
```

This continues for a few hundred lines, and then terminates with this:

```
pages/account/orders/completed function (err, v) {
            results[index] = v;
            callback(err);
        } undefined
pages/account/orders/invoice function (err, v) {
            results[index] = v;
            callback(err);
        } undefined
pages/account/orders/details function (err, v) {
            results[index] = v;
            callback(err);
        } undefined
pages/custom/page/narrow-page function (err, v) {
            results[index] = v;
            callback(err);
        } undefined
{ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'layout/base/function (err, v) {
            results[index] = v;
            callback(err);
        }.html']
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'layout/base/function (err, v) {\n            results[index] = v;\n            callback(err);\n        }.html' }
/Users/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/lib/template-assembler.js:27
            return callback(err);
                   ^

TypeError: callback is not a function
    at /Users/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/lib/template-assembler.js:27:20
    at /Users/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/lib/template-assembler.js:92:20
    at /Users/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:421:16
    at iteratorCallback (/Users/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:998:13)
    at /Users/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:906:16
    at ReadFileContext.callback (/Users/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/lib/template-assembler.js:113:24)
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:303:13)
```

Comment: In `template-assembler.js`, can you insert `console.log(err);` between lines 25 & 26 please? Once saved, please then attempt to open a file again and let me know what the output is (you will still get the stack trace with new text from the error above it).

Comment: I added the debug statement as you suggested and added the result to the questions. Does that help?

Comment: I also just downgraded to stencil-cli version 1.8.0, and the issue goes away. However, I still randomly see an error in the command line sometimes after saving a template file, and it seems like it might be related to the issue in version 1.12.0. For example, when I save the file `templates/components/common/header.html`, the cli shows: `[Error: The following template(s) are/is missing:
components/common/.header.html]`. However, the server does not shut down, it just outputs the error and continues running. It doesn't do this with all template files, just some. Maybe related to `.swp` files?

Comment: I think it's an issue with the library, I'm thinking most likely that the parameters for `assemble()` were passed out of required order or incorrectly somehow _(like the caller sent it too many or too less parameters and so now the sequence is out of order and so the passed params aren't properly being associated)_

Comment: Let's do this please..
Immediately after *Line 23* / the start of the `assemble()` function, please do a console.log for each one of the parameters - `templatesFolder, templates, callback`.
Then also, on *Line 111* (between `missingTemplates.push(templateFile);` & `return callback();` - please insert `console.log(err);` - this way we can see what the FS/ReadFile error is, and perhaps it will confirm my suspicion of the parameters being passed wrong / having incorrect values.

Comment: Thank you. I updated the question again with the output you requested

Comment: Looks like you were right https://github.com/bigcommerce/stencil-cli/issues/318

Comment: Sweet! BigCommerce, Node, & AWS is my expertise. Contact info located in profile, feel free to reach out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved with https://github.com/bigcommerce/stencil-cli/pull/319

Thanks for the quick report!